# I am having problems with my if statements

Tags: java, if-statement, logic

I am thoroughly struggling in my AP computer science class and have almost no idea whats going on. Ive been practicing on codingbat.com, but i still need some help with a couple errors:

> Syntax error on token “boolean", @ expected.

and:

> Syntax error on tokens, ClassHeader expected instead.

edit: Okay, so ive worked a bit on it, and came up with this

```js
public class sleepIn 
{
public static void main (String [] args)
 {
   boolean weekday=true; 
    boolean vacation=true;

      if(weekday==true && vacation==false)
      {
        return false;
      }
      if(weekday==false && vacation==true)
      {
        return true;
  }
}
}
```

```
public boolean sleepIn(boolean weekday, boolean vacation)
{
  public static void main (String [] args)
  {
    boolean weekday=true; 
    boolean vacation=true;

      if(weekday==true && vacation==false)
      {
        return false;
      }
  }
```

### }

```
I'm still getting errors on it, but now they are different. They are:
```

> File: C:\Users\ralph\Desktop\sleepIn.java  [line: 10]
>   Error: Void methods cannot return a value

and

> File: C:\Users\ralph\Desktop\sleepIn.java  [line: 14]
>   Error: Void methods cannot return a value

Comment: @NicolásStraub The tag says java not javascript

Comment: you cannot define main inside another function.  you want something like `class Something { public static void Main.... { } }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seemed to have declared the program's main function within another function. If you remove the

```
public static void main (String[] args){}
```

from the function it will work. The java program will require the main function but only defined within the class not another function.

//HERE IS MY EDIT TO EXPLAIN HOW YOU SHOULD HAVE WRITTEN THIS PROGRAM

```
public class MyClass {
    //I define the class here^^

    //Public function
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        //Here in the main function I will call the sleepIn 

        boolean sleepin = sleepIn(true,true);

        //I am setting weekday and vacation to true, it should in return print true
        System.out.println(sleepin); //It prints TRUE


    }

    //Your sleepIn function
    public static boolean sleepIn(boolean weekday, boolean vacation){
        if (weekday == true && vacation == true){

            //Here the function returns true (boolean)

            return true;
        }

        //The function returns false (boolean)

        return false;
    }
}
```

So to explain what is happening, I am defining a class, then within the class I have the main method (Where all code will be executed) and I have the sleepIn function (returns true or false based on input). As you can see when I call the sleepIn function with both prarams set as true within the main method, it returns a boolean (false) as expected. I then print the results.

Comment: I tried what you said, and all it did was return more errors. Any idea why?

Comment: The two errors you are returning are basically saying you need to return a boolean for the sleepIn function as well as you need to have a class. Are all your variables and functions defined within the programs class?

Comment: it returned one of the same errors, on top of three new ones; "Syntax error, insert ". class" to complete Expression", and "Syntax error, insert ")" to complete SingleMemberAnnotation", as well as "Syntax error, insert "interface Identifier" to complete InterfaceHeader".

Comment: It seems you have many syntax errors, check over your code to make sure it is correct. Can we see the whole program?

Comment: It is the whole program... :(

Comment: So first of all you need to declare a class for any java program, this is at the beginning of the file and starts with `class MyClass {//CODE HERE}` And within this class is where you will place your function and the main function **AS TWO SEPERATE FUNCTIONS** not together. For your sleepIn function, it requires a boolean return. So at the end of it simply return true or false depending on what you want.

Comment: Sorry, I'm very confused. Do you think you could include an example?

Comment: I will edit my answer with how to structure your code

Comment: Thank you so much! Something you did in that program reminded me of what my teacher said and i can now recollect how to do this. THANK YOU THANK YOU THANK YOU

Comment: You might want to change that if statement, it doesn't produce the correct output for most scenarios.

Comment: What do you mean @luckydog32 I just tested it and it works with all scenarios. (true, false) (false,false) (true,true) (false,true)

Comment: @Ethan what if its a weekend and not a vacation(false, false)? Or a vacation and a weekend(false, true)? You should still be able to sleep in right?

Comment: That is for @Andrew to add, I am not here to do his AP homework. I was simply explaining how he could make the code snippet he supplied work.

Comment: @Ethan Alright, I just think that if you are going to rewrite the method you might as well make it logically correct or at least say that the method isn't set up properly to give the desired output.

Comment: @Ethan For the record, this isn't homework. I'm trying to do a lil learning on my own. Again, thanks to both of you!

Answer (score 0):

So there's two issues with the code right now:

> Syntax error on token “boolean", @ expected.

Is caused from you not returning a boolean from this function since you defined it's return type as boolean, if you don't want to return anything change its return type to void:

```
public boolean sleepIn(boolean weekday, boolean vacation)
{
    //you need to return a boolean from here
}
```

Or:

```
public void sleepIn(boolean weekday, boolean vacation)
{
    //do things
}
```

Secondly you need to split up your methods, you cant embed one inside the other:

```
  public static void main (String [] args)
  {
    boolean weekday=true; 
    boolean vacation=true;

      if(weekday==true && vacation==false)
      {
        //return false; //your main shouldn't be returning anything since 
                        //there's nothing to return to
      }
  }

  public boolean sleepIn(boolean weekday, boolean vacation)
  {
        //you need to return a boolean from here
  }
```

You need to return a boolean in your method `sleepIn` because you defined that as your return type in the method head:

```
  public **boolean** sleepIn
```

Whatever you define in as your return type, your method needs to return a value of that type.

```
public class Test {

  public static void main (String[] args){
       boolean weekday=true; 
       boolean vacation=true;
       boolean result = sleepIn(weekday, vacation);
       System.out.println(result);
   }

   public static boolean sleepIn(boolean weekday, boolean vacation)
   {
       return (!weekday || vacation); //true if not a weekday or is a vac.
   }
}
```

Comment: I really appreciate the answer, but im kind of confused. I dont quite understand why i need to return a boolean directly underneath of a boolean, when no statement has declared it true or false.

Comment: @Andrew You don't need to return boolean right away, you just need to return it by the end of the method. You need to do this because you defined boolean as your return type in the method head `public boolean sleepIn(boolean weekday, boolean vacation)`.

Comment: I tried what you said, and the errors keep piling up. I'm very confused. It's probably due to my lack of knowledge, but if you have any other ideas, please let me know.

Comment: @Andrew I put in an edit for what I think your code should look like when its finished as part of ACV's post. If he doesn't accept it in a few minutes I'll just put it at the bottom of my post.

Comment: Thank you very much. I really appreciate it.

Comment: can u post it please?

Comment: @Andrew Sure, its at the bottom.

Comment: Yea, this is what was on their website, but i have no idea what the "| |" means, or what the "!" means in (!weekday || vacation);.

Comment: `||` means or and `!` means not. So `(!weekday || vacation)` reads as, _(not weekday) or vacation_.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have a method defined within another method which is not allowed. This would be a correct class:

```
public class Test {

      public static void main (String [] args){
           boolean result = sleepIn(true, true);
           System.out.println(result);
       }

    public static boolean sleepIn(boolean weekday, boolean vacation)
      {
        boolean weekday=true; 
        boolean vacation=true;

          if(weekday==true && vacation==false)
          {
            return false;
          }
      }
}
```

Comment: would it be okay if i linked u the problem and you can take a look at it. It's probably very very simple, but i am just not that great at coding.

Comment: you just need to try harder. That's all it takes to get successful